# android how to list files from other device

Tags: android, file, list, pushdown-automaton

i have another pda device. android phone and pda are connected to same wireless router. i can read files from pda if i know the filename. Now there is a folder called "reports" on pda. i need to show all files in report folder so user clicks on report generated on pda will open in webview.

Let say i have 
    [http://192.168.0.3/reports](http://example.com). I have tried few thing with File class in android that doesnot seem to work.

Please help if you can. Thanks

Comment: Consider running a local webserver on the "host" device, for example: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not using third party code.